# Get result of anonymous pl/sql block in scala

Tags: oracle, scala, jdbc

I am calling a function in scala to truncate table. I am able to call a function and able to truncate a table as well. But, I would also print the value of result. If the truncate is successfully then the function is returning 1 as Int and I would to like to print this value to make sure the operation is successful but I am not sure how to do it ?

**Query to call function :**

```
truncQuery = "declare
                  result number;
              begin
                  result := TRUNCATE_TABLE('PROV');
              end;"
```

The value is being stored in the result but how can I print the result in the scala code below?

**Code :**

```
def truncateTbl (truncQuery : String ): Unit ={

    val con = oracleUtil.auxdbOracleUtil()
    val callableStatement  = con.prepareCall(truncQuery)
    callableStatement.execute()

    callableStatement.close()
    con.close()
```

Comment: Did you try to look at what `callableStatement.execute()` gives you back?

Comment: Is TRUNCATE_TABLE('PROV'); a function which calls a some function with any RETURN? You are executing immediate into this created function?

Answer (score 0):

Your TRUNCATE_TABLE function must be like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION (PARAM_TABLE IN VARCHAR2)
RETURN NUMBER
AS
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE ' || PARAM_TABLE;
    RETURN 0
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
    RETURN 1
END;
/
```

Comment: Thanks for the input but this question is not about how the function code should look like ? I have the function code and I don't have access to modify it. The question is about the storing result of function.